# fatal: HEAD: no such path in the working tree while trying to delete file from history

Tags: git, github

I have added several very big HDF5 files into my local git repository. Now if I want to push it to github, I fail (by timeout or reject, I don't know).

How to remove these files from the history?

Or better, how to push it to github without these files?

I tried

```
>git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.hdf5' HEAD
fatal: HEAD: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
```

but failed.

Comment: It may be worth using [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) rather than trying to concoct arcane Git spells ;)

Comment: Perhaps, the files are not in the root directory? Maybe you need `rm **/*.hdf5`